# NumberFormatException error - Android

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I get NumberFormatException error at this line of my code. What should i do?

```
String employ = intent.getStringExtra("employeeid").trim();
spinEmployee.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(employ)-1);
```

Comment: what's the value of `employ` here?

Comment: what is `employ`?? and post the stacktrace

Comment: maybe value of employ is null when you are calling the code

Comment: post more relevant code for better understand.

Comment: @GopalRao its a string. String employ = intent.getStringExtra("employeeid").trim();

Comment: @Raghunandan String employ = intent.getStringExtra("employeeid").trim();

Comment: @ARK I edited my code. Please check it

Comment: @HamidShatu I edited my code please check

Comment: @jajaja whatever its not a valid integer. hence the exception

Comment: It says invalid int: "0~"

Comment: @jajaja post the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this by adding `try catch block`.

Create one method to get valid int from string like this

```
public int getValidIntFromString(String inputstring) {

    if (inputstring!= null) {
        if (!inputstring.equals("")) {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(inputstring);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("Error-- > ", e.toString());
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can convert string to int by calling this

```
int intemploy = getValidIntFromString(employ);
```

Here `employ` will be your String from where you want to parse Int from String.

**Note:**  if you get `employ` data from `EditText` then please set `inputType="number"` in xml file to avoid such kind of Exception.

Just like this

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/myEditText"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="number" />
```

Comment: i seen your updated code you may pass integer value in putExtra.

Comment: Just comment line where you want to parse string to int, and log employ value with `Log.i("Dev", employ);`

Comment: @BlackTiger intent.putExtra("employeeid", employeeid); This is where it came from. How should I change it to integer?

Comment: Try to get String Extra by this `String employ = getIntent().getStringExtra("employeeid");`.  my be your intent is null so try this code for get data.

Answer (score 1):

The exception says the format of EMPLOY is not valid,maybe it's a String like '2d','33a'